# Compiler Error? Java BinarySearch

Tags: java, binary-search

So I'm running into an issue with my program. I'm trying to modify the BinarySearch so that I can get a pair of numbers. I'm trying to determine where in the sorted array there are multiple instances of a number x. I need to display just the first and last index to the screen. I keep adding a couple if statements but when I do that I don't get any comparison to happen. Now when I try to return a Pair(left, right) I get the error: cannot find symbol on that particular line of code. I don't currently have anything for checking left or right. I was just trying to get my code to compile but I can't get that to work right now. Any input would be helpful. Not asking for you to do my work for me, just a little nudge in the right direction.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test_BinarySearchDup{

private static class Pair{
    public int left;
    public int right;

    public Pair(int left, int right){
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    String file = args[0];
    int x = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    Scanner fin = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
    int count = 0;
    while(fin.hasNext()){
        fin.nextInt();
        count++;
    }
    fin.close();

    int[] array = new int[count];

    fin = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
    while(fin.hasNext()){
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            array[i] = fin.nextInt();
        }
    }
    fin.close();

    Pair numbers =  BinarySearchDup(array, x, 0, (array.length - 1));
    System.out.println("[" + numbers.left + "," + numbers.right + "]");
}

public static Pair BinarySearchDup(int[] A, int x, int low, int high){
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    int left = 0, right = 0;
    while(low <= high){
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if(A[mid] == x){ //if A[mid] == x we need to check left and right to make sure that there are no other copies of the number
            //checking to the left
            return BinarySearchDup(A, x, low, mid - 1);
        }
        else if(A[mid] < x)
            return BinarySearchDup(A, x, mid + 1, high);
        else
            return BinarySearchDup(A, x, low, mid - 1);
    }
    return new Pair(left, right);
}
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? What line causes the error?

Comment: Test_BinarySearchDup.java:55: error: cannot find symbol

on the last line of BinarySearch, the return Pair(left, right)

Comment: After you replied, I see that you did in fact include the error in your original question. It's hiding inside your description. For future reference, you should make the error message more obvious so we can pick it out easily. I suggest that you place an error message in its own paragraph separate from your description. You can add a ">" before the first line of the error message and add two spaces at the end of each line to hightlite it. Also be sure to include the *entire* error message.

Comment: If I do two calls of the BinarySearch will that mess up the time complexity of the entire search? I'm supposed to keep the TC at logn for the entire thing. Would it be easiest to call it twice to get the left most and the right most copy and then just make the Pair at the end of the program?

Comment: If you implement a true binary search, the time complexity *is* logn. As a consequence, if your code has TC that is *not* logn, then it *isn't* a binary search.

Comment: p.s. Is there a reason that you are returning a `Pair` rather than simply an index into the array being searched?

Comment: And you have two branches in your if...else if..else that do the same thing. This means you can reduce it to an if...else.

Comment: Why does your binary search have a loop *and* a recursive call? The loop will either never execute or repeat infinitely because `high` and `low` never change inside of it.

Comment: Unless I'm reading this wrong...
The specification of the function that implements the modified binary search algorithm is:
public static Pair BinarySearchDup(int[] A, int x)
where (1) the array A stores the data that the program read from the given input data file, (2) x stores
the value that is supplied by the command line, and (3) Pair is a class that you can define as follows
in order for you to return two integers by the above function 2.
class Pair{
public int left;
public int right;
}

Comment: Since that's what your specification says, then let's go with it. I'm not familiar with the *modified* binary search. Even with a normal binary search, I can see why you might want a range rather than just a single index. There are certainly more important things to change in your code. Good luck with it and feel free to post more questions as you get stuck.

Comment: The modified binary search is something that we have to come up with ourselves. I'm struggling to try and figure out what needs to be changed and how to make BinarySearch stay the same as far as Time Complexity goes. If I start to add loops and stuff doesn't that affect the TC of the entire algorithm?

Comment: How does this "modified" binary search differ from a normal binary search?

Comment: The way that he described it in class was that we have to use it to be able to search both left and right of a number to make sure that there aren't any duplicates, but shouldn't that affect the time complexity of things if we did that? i understand that we are going to have to do things recursively.

Comment: No, it shouldn't if you implement it correctly. It sounds like you need to modify your `if(A[mid] == x)` branch to find the range of all elements that are the same.

Comment: wouldn't I have to implement a couple loops in order to get the right output from the `if(A[mid] == x)` I would have to recursively do some stuff to check the solutions wouldn't I. I would have to have a couple of cases to check left and right.

Comment: That sounds about right. In other words, the loops need to be *inside* the if branch, not wrapped around the whole if...else if...else statement. After you write something that works, then go back and do the analysis to see if it runs in logn. If not, *then* go back and find a way that will do better. In other words, don't try to optimize yet.

Comment: ok. I just want to get it working before I worry about the logn thing ha.

Comment: I'm having issues trying to figure out how to get it to check left and right separately. I can get it to check one direction but not the other.

Comment: I suggest using two different loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will fix your syntax error:

Change

```
return Pair(left, right);
```

to

```
return new Pair(left, right);
       ^^^
```

I haven't checked the logic of your code, though.

Comment: wow....i can't believe I missed that!